Bulk Transfer of Android to Zebra Printer, just working on Android 9
I developed an application in Unity, which prints labels for Zebra.
To communicate with the Zebra Printer, I developed a module in Java, in Android Studio, which performs this communication.
After reading Google's documentation very well (which is a little confusing), I developed it, followed it step by step, and tested it...
On a tablet with Android 9.0 it worked perfectly, and the Bulk Tranfer result is around 6k.
Next, I tested it on computers with Android 7.1.2, the USB permissions are requested, I click on Ok, it finds the interface and the endpoint, it connects correctly, but when it gets to the bulk transfer part, the result it gives is -1.
I've already tried changing the manifest permissions, but nothing!
What could it be?
I would appreciate it if someone could help me.
Thanks.
Here are some important parts of the code:
Gets permissions:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.registerReceiver(br, filter, "android.permission.USB_PERMISSION", null);
        } else {
            context.registerReceiver(br, filter);
            //context.registerReceiver(br, filter, "android.permission.USB_PERMISSION", null);
        }

        //ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, br, filter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.aconfeitaria.printpdf.USB_PERMISSION_REQUEST");
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=31) {
            Request_Return = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        }else{
            Request_Return = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        }
usbManager.requestPermission(current_device, Request_Return);

Gets interface and endpoint:
public UsbInterface Get_Device_Interface(UsbDevice _device) {
        int interface_count = _device.getInterfaceCount();
        UsbInterface usbInterface = null;
        if (interface_count > 0) {
            //usbInterface = _device.getInterface(0);
            UsbInterface usbInterface_current =null;
            for(int i=0; i<interface_count; i++){
                usbInterface_current = _device.getInterface(i);
                if(usbInterface_current.getInterfaceClass()== UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_PRINTER){
                    usbInterface = usbInterface_current;
                    Log.d("Found device interface", String.valueOf(usbInterface_current.getInterfaceClass()));
                    break;
                }
                /*Log.d("interface class", String.valueOf(_device.getInterface(i).getInterfaceClass()));
                Log.d("interface name", String.valueOf(_device.getInterface(i).getName()));*/
            }
        }

        return usbInterface;
    }

    public UsbEndpoint Get_Device_Endpoint_ByInterface(UsbInterface usbInterface, UsbDevice _device) {
        UsbEndpoint endpoint = null;

        if(usbInterface!=null){
            for (int i = 0; i < usbInterface.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                endpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(i);
                if (endpoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT && endpoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                    return endpoint;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

Make the bulk transfer:
 int result = usbManager.connection.bulkTransfer(usbManager.endpoint, buffer, buffer.length, 5000);
                                Log.d("result",String.valueOf(result));


Please add the dependencies for the code provided. Also clean it a bit (e.g. remove commented out code) in order to let the users focus on what is important.
Clarify what do you mean with bulk transfer in this specific context.
